# microsoft-identity-express - Why can't I successfully sign in?

Tags: node.js, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-identity-platform, microsoft-identity-web

I am trying to connect my NodeJs Express App to the Microsoft Graph API so that I can send automated emails. So far, I've been following [this guide](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-nodejs-tutorial/blob/main/2-Authorization/1-call-graph/README.md) to connect my app to the [microsoft-identify-express](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/microsoft-identity-express) package with the hope that it will allow me to authenticate myself into my Azure app and give me access to the API.

Here is my msIdSettings:

```js
const msIdAuthSettings = {
    appCredentials: {
        clientId: "...",
        tenantId: "...",
        clientSecret: "..."
    },
    authRoutes: {
        redirect: "/redirect",
        unauthorized: "/unauthorized",
        error: "/error"
    },
    protectedResources: {
        graphAPI: {
            endpoint: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",
            scopes: ["user.read", "mail.send"]
        },
        armAPI: {
            endpoint: "https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2020-01-01",
            scopes: ["https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation"]
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my app setup:

```js
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const cors = require('cors');

const MsIdExpress = require('microsoft-identity-express');
const msIdAuthSettings = require('./msIdAuthSettings');

const emailRouter = require('./routes/email');

require('dotenv').config();

const server = express();

server.use(cors());
server.use(express.json());

server.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        secure: false, // set this to true on production
    }
}));

// instantiate the wrapper
const msid = new MsIdExpress.WebAppAuthClientBuilder(msIdAuthSettings).build();

// initialize the wrapper
server.use(msid.initialize());

// setup the routers
server.use('/email', emailRouter(msid));

module.exports = server;
```

And here is my emailRouter:

```js
const router = require('express').Router();

const msIdAuthSettings = require('../msIdAuthSettings');

module.exports = (msid) => {
    // auth routes
    router.get('/signin',
        msid.signIn({
            postLoginRedirect: "/",
        }),
    );

    router.get('/signout',
        msid.signOut({
            postLogoutRedirect: "/",
        }),
    );

    // unauthorized
    router.get('/unauthorized', (req, res) => res.redirect('/401.html'));

    router.get('*', (req, res) => res.redirect('/404.html'));

    return router;
}
```

When I hit the `/signin` endpoint, it successfully takes me to the authorize step and has me login to my Microsoft account, but after I login, it redirects to the endpoint configured in `msIdAuthSettings.authRoutes.unauthorized`:

[Inspect Element -> Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A0mN.png)

I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/microsoft-identity-express), and I think it must be failing at [this step](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/microsoft-identity-express/blob/2d889792b48e5ccb06ea36d8e3db75a242db1a52/src/client/webapp/MsalWebAppAuthClient.ts#L174-L176), but I have no idea why.

I would really appreciate any help or suggestion with this, because I've already spent two days on it and I'd like to move on with my life!

Answer (score 0):

404 error denotes that the requested `resource is not available`.
So please make sure the redirect url/reply url in app authentication request  is matching the one in azure ad portal i.e.; Please double check that your redirect URIs are valid endpoints and has `https` protocol for other than local host and make sure user is granted permissions .

```
#To catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    next(createError(404));
});
```

[How to handle 404 error in express? Example program (techeplanet.com)](https://techeplanet.com/how-to-handle-404-error-in-express/#:%7E:text=Once%20express%20gets%20a%20request%2C%20it%20looks%20for,error%20instead%20its%20a%20resource%20not%20found%20scenario.)

- Please make sure you have given correct value for client secret .It
  must be clientsecret value and not client secret Id. [image]
- Also please make sure to grant admin consent for the scopes that you
  have in azure portal or please check the same with admin

**Reference**:

[Tutorial: Sign in users in a Node.js & Express web app - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-webapp-msal)